# vscode regex get lines with duplicate strings separated by comma

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode file with the following text:

```
"070230107121","46969","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"070230107121","46970","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"070230107121","47332","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"070230107121","47333","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"070230107121","47333","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"070230107121","46968","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"07087","46968","petcarerx","petcarerx"
"07087","46968","petcarerx","petcarerx"
```

If I do ctrl+f regex expression `^(.*)(\n\1)+$` it will find the identical lines, so in this case it finds two cases of identical lines:
[image]

I am trying to create a regular expression to find all lines where the first column is identical. so in this case; find all rows where the string that comes before the first comma is identical.

This regex expression gets everything before the first comma; `^(.+?),`, is there someway I can combine that with my first regex expression to get all lines that are identical before the first comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?),.*(?:\n\1,.*)+$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` inline backreference can refer to it from the regex pattern, `$1` if you need to refer to it from the replacement pattern)
- `,` - a comma
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n\1,.*)+` - 1 or more repetitions of a line break, then the same value as in Group 1 and then a comma and the rest of the line
- `$` - end of a line.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/dJ5HFP/1).

Tested in VS Code:

[image]

Comment: thank you, is there some way I could generalize this to work for the second column? so match items after the second comma?

Comment: @Martin `^((?:.*?,){2}).*(?:\n\1.*)+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ5HFP/2)).